# Deliberately mispronouncing words

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, errors

Is there a word for the deliberate mispronunciation of words in order to confuse people, or to start a new trend of pronunciation?

Ex. He often tried to impress us with his wit and wordplay, but his speech was so full of ___________ that we had difficulty understanding him.

Comment: Eee cawn't eyemagine thut enywun wood ebber dough setch e ting!

Comment: Don't know the word, but there are some diff types: Corny granny delib. mispronunciation: e.g., whores ovaries; wordnerd ironic eggcorn delib. mispronunciation: e.g., eXpresso; hipster slang delib. mispronunciation (dated): e.g., schweet!

Comment: What have you found out before posting? The first google result gives several suggestions.

Comment: Davo, I found "Hyperforeignism" and "catachresis", neither of which is quite right. The Wikipedia page for hyperforeignism gives the examples of what I am looking for - "Although similar, words that exhibit deliberate language-play (such as pronouncing Report with a silent ⟨t⟩ in The Colbert Report or ironically pronouncing Target as /tɑːrˈʒeɪ/ tar-zhay, as though it were an upscale boutique) are not, strictly speaking, hyperforeignisms. These are, instead, a way of poking fun at those who earnestly adopt foreign-sounding pronunciations of pseudo-loanwords."

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnX-EPaAIdU.  That's referred to as malapropism.

Answer (score 4):

I like malapropism for it as well but I feel like describing it as "fatuous malapropism" helps to clarify that it's being done porpoisefully. I also feel like it doesn't quite cover the intentional *misspelling* of words that is frequently a component. Like "doge" instead of dog or "birb" instead of bird.

Whether I personally find the practice funny or not isn't relevant – I just think it's too widespread at this point for it not to have it's own word.

Comment: Hi Pete, welcome to EL&U. Note, this site is different from others: it's not a forum for opinions or personal descriptions. An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I feel your post would be more suitable as a *comment*; as an answer, it's incorrect, and I feel I have no choice but to downvote it. By definition, all malapropisms are (a) **ignorant** rather than deliberate and (b) fatuous (so adding the adjective doesn't clarify it at all). NB for guidance on what's expected, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Hi Pete,  I don't see how a forum about English "Usage" can expect to be detailed,  authoritative or correct. Your experience of language usage is as valid as mine. I like 'fatuous malapropism'. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

A Language Log item from April 3, 2008, "[Saying It Wrong on Porpoise](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005524.html)," doesn't identify a comprehensive technical term beyond ***intentional mispronunciation***:

> Grant Barrett is now doing a weekly language column for the *Malaysia Star*, and this week he talks about saying things the wrong way on purpose — intentional errors like the Internets and coinkydink. The column got picked up by [Jason Kottke's blog](http://kottke.org/08/04/saying-words-wrong-on-purpose), where commenters are chiming in with their own examples.
>
> Just in case anyone thought this was a new phenomenon (hello again, Recency Illusion), an article on "Intentional Mispronunciations" appeared in the journal *American Speech* way back in 1932. If you don't have access to JSTOR and you're not a member of the American Dialect Society, you'll have to make do with this recent summary by Larry Horn on the ADS mailing list:
>
> > Margaret Reed (1932), "Intentional Mispronunciations". *American Speech* 7: 192-99.
> >
> > This covers what Reed took to be a fad among the "light-hearted youth" of Central Westerners (she's writing from Nebraska) to circulate...well, intentional mispronunciations. (She's following up on a paper by Louise Pound from 10 years earlier in *Dialect Notes*.) Her categories include everything from adding or subtracting syllables and restressing (antique as "an-tee-cue", "champeen", "the-'ater"), tensing lax vowels ("genu-wine"), borrowing of "vulgar" pronunciations ("agin", "extry", "who'd-a thunk it", "varmint"), "Al Smith" English [a.k.a. Brooklynese, not a moniker Reed herself applies] ("boid", "noives", "toity-toid street", "winegar woiks"), the "extremely annoying" affectation of children's speech ("sojer", "sword" [with /w/, as we've been discussing recently], "Injun", "ax" for 'ask' [!-- she does add 'also archaic' for this], "itty bitty"), Yiddishisms ("epple", "darlink", "dun't esk"), various other dialect borrowings ("enyhoo", "pitcher" [for 'picture'], "divil"), blends and folk etymological forms ("bumbershoot", "brass-ear", "animule", "absotively"), misdivisions ("a tall", "a norange", but not "a whole nother"), spelling pronunciations ("k-nife", "g-nat", "X-mas"), and so on. She ends with the wistful hope that while "human nature" may be responsible for perpetuating this fad (or these fads--unclear how many causal factors are involved), "surely, in its fullest and most extreme form, the phenomenon is now passing its peak".

The summary of Read's article is useful for identifying what species of mispronunciation a particular derangement falls into. For example *I-rack* and *A-rab* fall into the restressing subcategory, *pisgeddy* into the affectation of children's speech, *bidniss* is regional imitative (in this case, G.W. Bush Texan), and *miv-sivvum* (a pronunciation I picked up from Enoch Emery in *Wise Blood*, who is trying to sound out the word "MVSEVM" as carved in stark capital letters on a building's edifice) is a spelling pronunciation.

The earlier article (mentioned above in Larry Horn's summary of Reed's article) on the phenomenon—Louise Pound, "[Intentional Mispronunciations in the Central West](https://books.google.com/books?id=lxwOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=intentional+mispronunciation&source=bl&ots=YkuLYKiXtb&sig=uzmrz_G09VUKPYtL4sd5TUC9QCY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOxr77rJ7SAhXIqFQKHU8eAs8Q6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=intentional%20mispronunciation&f=false)," in *Dialect Notes*, volume 5, part 5 (1922)—is available for reading in its entirety at no charge through Google Books. Pound offers detailed categories including "process syllable division" (such as "a ninfindel"); "stretch forms" (such as "be-youtiful"); "syllable inversions" (such as "ossifer"), and "blends" (such as "democrazy"). It's a fairly brief but interesting survey of the subject.

None of these resources ventures beyond *intentional mispronunciation* as a blanket term for the phenomenon. Pound and Read do try to give names to the subcategories of mispronunciation that they discuss, but they don't seem to use the same terminology (judging from Pound's article and the summary of Reed's).

Comment: In retrospect, I think **mispronounciation** would be a perfect term for the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Mumpsimus: And lastly, there's one more type of wrongism to investigate, the mumpsimus.
This type of... Read more at https://www.higgypop.com/news/intentional-mispronunciation/

Comment: Sorry; as the article points out, 'mumpsimus' does not apply to _deliberately_ making mistakes, which OP clearly specifies.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: a malapropism is a malapropism whether intended or not. OED: malapropism, n. **The ludicrous misuse of words**, esp. in mistaking a word for another resembling it; an instance of this. -- 1890   Harper's Mag. Apr. 664/1   *Lemaître has reproached Shakespeare for his love of Malapropisms*.-- It does not matter if it is done for effect or accidentally. --[Of Sellars and Yeatman]‘*They wrote, among other things, 1066 and All That, in which they frequently made use of malapropisms* - http://jjbeazley.blogspot.com/2016/02/

Comment: @Greybeard And this is relevant because? (Unless you're aiming at a joke.)

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Hmm... I read "*Sorry; as the article points out, '**malapropism**' does not apply to deliberately making mistakes*, I must get some new glasses.